# How to send events to all instances of the application in PCF

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcf

I am not able to find a way to send/broadcast a message to all application instances in Pivotal Cloud Foundry. How can we notify to all app instances of some events? If we use the HTTP request, PCF router will dispatch it to a single instance of the app. How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What @Florian said is probably the safer option, but if you want something quick and easy, you can send HTTP requests directly to an app instance by using the `X-CF-APP-INSTANCE` header. The format for the header is `YOUR-APP-GUID:YOUR-INSTANCE-INDEX`.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/http-routing.html#app-instance-routing

So given an app guid, you could iterate over the number of instances, say 0 to 5, and send an HTTP request to each one. Make sure to check the response to confirm that each one succeeded.

This also requires that you know the app guid for your app (i.e. `cf app <name> --guid`) and the number of instances of your app.

Comment: Yep.. @Florian solution could be used for frequent/safer. Buy my case is just turn on the flag on run time and not often too.

Answer (score 1):

CF, out of the box, does not provide any event queue mechanism where apps can subscribe to.

What I would do (assuming you've two app instances A and B):

- Provide an event endpoint in your application code, e.g. POST /api/event (alternatively, if the event should arise from another app (e.g. another microservice), this one could directly send messages onto the queue)
- All app instances are listening on an *internal event queue* for new events
- instance A receives the call from the CF router and processes it by issuing an event on an *internal event queue*, the instance *will not* react to the event, yet
- When A publishes the event, A and B receives the event and processes it accordingly

Now, the *internal event queue* you can use highly depends on your deployment. On AWS you probably can use [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/de/sqs/) or [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/de/sns/) or something similar. PCF, as I know, may also provide a messaging system which would suit here as well, [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/). You could also use features of other services that would allow you to subscribe to events, such as [redis (pub/sub commands)](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub) or similar.

If you provide more information about what you want to achieve more concretely, more detailed answer would be possible, though.

Comment: Florian +1 for your solution. But it is not matching/suit my case.