# Execute REST call on all Pivotal Cloud Foundry instances

Tags: cloud-foundry

We deploy our Spring Boot microservices to PCF. Depending upon the load we might have multiple instances running. We have a custom cache invalidation REST API call to invalidate the custom cache we use. Is there any way for this REST API call to invalidate the cache in all the instances? We might have 1 to 3 instances for the application.

Comment: Having the cache as per-instance state is a bad idea, for exactly this reason. See e.g. https://12factor.net/backing-services.

Comment: Ours is a different requirement. I just made it simple to understand. Is there anyway to execute the restAPI on all the instances?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60042784/3001761; you can send a request to [a specific instance](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/http-routing.html#app-instance-routing), so you could get all the app IDs then hit each index in turn.